# Dell Inspiron 6000 running xp won't work properly

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 6000 laptop running Windows XP will turn on - the three indicator lights on the screen hinge come on, as do all the indicators on the laptop itself. The power indicator stays on, the disk and battery indicators each flash twice, then stay off. Only the power indicator and the lock with the '9' stay on. Have a monitor hooked up to the laptop, and nothing ever comes up on the screen at all. Monitor always works fine, tested it with a pc and it works. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to laptops.

This happens regardless of whether I am using the battery or have the laptop plugged in.

Comment: Sounds like a dead laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging it and holding the power key down for at least 30 seconds.  After releasing the power key plug it back in and try to start it up.

Comment: He can try this, but also remove the battery for at least a minute so any capacitors discharge.

Comment: Its a good suggestion @KCotreau.

Comment: @avirk Thanks...still sounds like it's dead. :(

Comment: I work with 100's of laptops and desktops.  This method resets the power system and solves the problem more often then not.  Especially in cases when "The power indicator stays on".  I have not had to remove the batteries on laptops to do this.

Comment: I tend to hold the power button for 40-50 seconds for good measure

Comment: I tried your suggestion several times Kevin. Now the low battery indicator flashes constantly, but still nothing comes up on screen.  I expect my battery is no good and neither is the third party charger that came with the laptop.  Funny, I ran this laptop for several months with no problems until this happened.

Comment: If you can borrow or buy a charger that would be the next thing to try.  If a defiantly good charger fails then the motherboard has power issues and would need replaced.  If it is still under warranty the company will replace the charger or the motherboard.